# How to specify the service region for a LocalBusiness?

Tags: seo, microdata, schema.org

How can I show Googlebot by attributes from Schema.org the geographic area where the services are available?

Our services are available in cities and in their vicinity:

- Walsall
- Dudley
- Wolverhampton
- Cannock

Or how I can say that the services are available in Walsall and 10 miles from this location?

I found only the examples https://schema.org/LocalBusiness#examples, but I have this more complex and I don't know how to do it.

I have mulitple locations and this is my problem. I know, I probably must use `LocalBusiness` → `areaServed`, but what's next?
How use `GeoShape` and `GeoCircle` and how print more locations than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide Schema.org properties multiple times.

So each `Service` can have multiple `areaServed` values:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
  <ul>
    <li itemprop="areaServed">…</li>
    <li itemprop="areaServed">…</li>
    <li itemprop="areaServed">…</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for answer.
It isn't fault to replace Service with LocalBusiness, it is?
What about services or GeoShape and GeoCircle.
If you could I would be very grateful.

Comment: @Bart: If you specify `areaServed` for `LocalBusiness`, it conveys which areas this business serves. If you specify it on `Service`, it conveys in which areas this specific service (which is possibly provided by a `LocalBusiness`) is served.

Comment: @Bart: `GeoShape` and its sub-type `GeoCircle` are possible values for the `areaServed` property. But you could also provide [`AdministrativeArea`](http://schema.org/AdministrativeArea), [`Place`](http://schema.org/Place) or even plain text as value. -- If you provide a service everywhere in a city, it’s the easiest to use the [`City`](http://schema.org/City) type (which is a sub-type of `AdministrativeArea`) as value.